# Azure templates running through an array

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

Im fairly new to using azure templates for deployments and have been working on one that deploys a set of virtual machines. In the first iteration of the template i set it up to read through a parameters file and specified the virtual machine name as a parameter - this parameter was used to form the NIC name and also the OS disk name.

What im attempting to do now is setup the template to create multiple virtual machines based on an array in the parameters.

I've setup the parameter

```
    "virtualMachineName": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            "VM-WEB01",
            "VM-WEB02"
        ]
```

then in the template file i've referenced it similar to this

```
"networkInterfaceName":  "[concat(toUpper(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()]),'-NIC')]"
"name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()],'-osDisk')]",
```

etc.

i've then used the copy option at the end of the resources section but before the outputs section in the template

```
 "copy": {
        "name": "vmcopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
      }
```

when trying to deploy the template i get an error saying the virtualMachineName paramter is null.

any pointers in where i am going wrong would be appreciated.

this is the full template

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
        "type": "array"
    },
    "subnetName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            "PROD-VM-RDGW01",
            "PROD-VM-RDGW02"
        ]
    },
    "virtualMachineRG": {
        "type": "array"
    },
    "osDiskType": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "availabilitySetName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "availabilitySetPlatformFaultDomainCount": {
        "type": "int"
    },
    "availabilitySetPlatformUpdateDomainCount": {
        "type": "int"
    },
    "backupVaultName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "backupFabricName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "backupVaultRGName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "backupVaultRGIsNew": {
        "type": "bool"
    },
    "backupPolicyName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "backupItemName": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "networkInterfaceName":  "[concat(toUpper(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()]),'-NIC')]",
    "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
    "vnetId": "[parameters('virtualNetworkId')]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        },
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
            }
        },
        "tags": {
            "billTO": "IT",
            "Environment": "Production",
            "projectName": "RDS"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "vmNICCopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
        },
        "tags": {
            "billTO": "IT",
            "Environment": "Production",
            "projectName": "RDS"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex())]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', parameters('availabilitySetName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "osDisk": {
                    "createOption": "fromImage",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()],'-osDisk')]",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                    }
                },
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                    "offer": "WindowsServer",
                    "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
                    "version": "latest"
                }
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex())]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                "windowsConfiguration": {
                    "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                    "provisionVmAgent": true
                }
            },
            "licenseType": "Windows_Server",
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
                "bootDiagnostics": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "storageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]"
                }
            },
            "availabilitySet": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('availabilitySetName'))]"
            }
        },

        "tags": {
            "billTO": "IT",
            "Environment": "Production",
            "projectName": "RDS"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "vmCopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('availabilitySetName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "platformFaultDomainCount": "[parameters('availabilitySetPlatformFaultDomainCount')]",
            "platformUpdateDomainCount": "[parameters('availabilitySetPlatformUpdateDomainCount')]"
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "Aligned"
        },
        "tags": {
            "billTO": "IT",
            "Environment": "Production",
            "projectName": "RDS"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()], '-' , 'BackupIntent')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('backupVaultRGName')]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('backupVaultName'), '/', parameters('backupFabricName'), '/', parameters('backupItemName'))]",
                        "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
                        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
                        "properties": {
                            "friendlyName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()], 'BackupIntent')]",
                            "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
                            "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('backupVaultRGName'), 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('backupVaultName'), parameters('backupPolicyName'))]",
                            "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineRG'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()])]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "vmNICCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineRG'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', [concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex())])]]"
        ]
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in principle this should be fine, since you didnt provide the whole template its hard to tell what is wrong exactly, but you should be able to craft a working example by modifying the basic example from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-copy-index-loops/azuredeploy.json) and using your bit instead of the one in the example (you'd also need to fix the parameter to be an array):

```
"copy": {
    "name": "vmcopy",
    "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
}
```

fix should be this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()], '-' , 'BackupIntent')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "resourceGroup": "[parameters('backupVaultRGName')]",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('backupVaultName'), '/', parameters('backupFabricName'), '/', parameters('backupItemName'))]",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
                    "properties": {
                        "friendlyName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()], 'BackupIntent')]",
                        "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
                        "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('backupVaultRGName'), 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('backupVaultName'), parameters('backupPolicyName'))]",
                        "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineRG'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex()])]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "copy": {
        "name": "vmNICCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineRG'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', [concat(parameters('virtualMachineName')[copyIndex())])]]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks - updated the question with the full template

Comment: thanks - im still getting this error New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 14:08:35 - Error: Code=InvalidDeploymentParameterValue; Message=The value of deployment parameter 'virtualMachineName' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter

Comment: okay, judging by the [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-recovery-services-backup-vms/azuredeploy.json#L46) you need to create a really long name for each backup item (and it has to be different for each item), so that is an issue for sure

Comment: i tried to delete the backup section all together, and still shows the same error

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly mean by 'backup section'. what happens if you delete the last resource (the deployment one) in the template altogether? does it work without that?

Comment: the section you posted is for the vm backups, so i removed that entire section

Comment: how are you starting the deployment

Comment: new-azresourcegroupdeployment -resourgroupname xxxxx -templatefile xxxxx -templateparameterfile xxxxx